# Does anchor check for program owned account?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, security

For security reasons, I know that we should check for the account owner of certain accounts. Although, if I recall correctly, Anchor already does this by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you load the account in the account context.

**Account** ([docs.rs](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/0.26.0/anchor_lang/accounts/account/struct.Account.html))

Wrapper around AccountInfo that verifies program ownership and deserializes underlying data into a Rust type.

```
pub escrow: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

**AccountLoader** ([docs.rs](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/0.26.0/anchor_lang/accounts/account_loader/struct.AccountLoader.html))

Type facilitating on demand zero copy deserialization. Will check the owner and discriminator.

```
pub state: AccountLoader<'info, VrfClient>,
```

**AccountInfo** ([docs.rs](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/0.26.0/anchor_lang/prelude/struct.AccountInfo.html))

No checks, loaded straight from the slot leader processing your transaction.

```
#[account(signer)]
pub authority: AccountInfo<'info>,
```

Comment: After all this time, I think I finally get it.
The AccountLoader will only check for ownership after a load or load_mut is called (thus being on-demand) - will fail during execution. Unlike the Account which will check before Tx execution - will fail before execution?